# Kafka Exception while Committing Offset Using commitAsync

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My Kafka application reads real time streaming data, process it and stores into Hive.I am trying to commit offset using `commitAsync`. 
I am getting below exception:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being
>   serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is
>   because the DStream object is being referred to from within the
>   closure. Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid
>   this. This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks with
>   unnecessary objects.

Below is the workflow of my code:

```java
public void method1(SparkConf conf,String app) 
    spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(conf.get("")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
    final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(context,
                new Duration(<spark duration>));
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamContext,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(<topicnames>, <kafka Params>));
    messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {
                OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
                JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
                        return tuple2.value();
                    }
                });

                records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                        if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                            methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                        }
                    }
                 });
                ((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
        }
    });
    javaStreamContext.start();
    javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

---

The below code works and commit offset after the data processing.
But the issue is, it is processing duplicates in the below case:
Lets say- The consumer job is running and the hive table has 0 records and the current offset is(FORMAT- fromOffest, untilOffset, Difference):
512 512  0
Then i produced 1000 records, and by the time it read 34 records but not committed, i killed it
512 546  34

I see that by this time, the 34 recs has already been loaded to the Hive table

Next, i restarted the application.
I see that it again reads the 34 records(instead of reading 1000-34=76 recs) although it has already processed them and loaded to Hive
512 1512  1000
And then after few seconds it gets updated.
1512 1512  0
Hive now has (34+1000=1034)

This causes duplicates records(extra 34) in the Table.
As mentioned in the code, i am committing the offset only after processing/loading to Hive table.

Please suggest.

```
public void method1(SparkConf conf,String app) 
spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(conf.get("")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(context,
            new Duration(<spark duration>));
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(<topicnames>, <kafka Params>));

            JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
                    return tuple2.value();
                }
            });

            records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                    if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                        methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                    }
                }
             });

             messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {
                    OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
                    ((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);                     
                    for (OffsetRange offset : offsetRanges) {
                        System.out.println(offset.fromOffset() + " " + offset.untilOffset()+ "  "+offset.count());
                    }
                     }
              });             
javaStreamContext.start();
javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
```

}

Comment: If all you would like to do is write Kafka data to Hive, then my suggestion would be to use Kafka Connect rather than writing your own Spark code. If you need to filter/process messages before they get to Hive, then write those results back to Kafka, then use the connector on that topic.

Comment: But Currently i need to fix the above kafka exception as there are multiple streaming jobs which are running on Spark using CreateDirectStream API and its not possible to convert all of them to use Kafka Connect. Appreciate any solution to handle this exception

Comment: Well, read the error... *DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure*... I cannot see your `methodToSaveDataInHive` call, but the problem is maybe there becauase you seem to exactly be doing this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself

Comment: methodToSaveDataInHive is just a method where i am converting the rdd to a Dataset<Row> and writing to hive table

Answer (score 1):

Try moving ((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges); out of  foreachRDD block

```
public void method1(SparkConf conf,String app) 
    spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(conf.get("")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
    final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(context,
                new Duration(<spark duration>));
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamContext,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(<topicnames>, <kafka Params>));
    messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {
                OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
                JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
                        return tuple2.value();
                    }
                });

                records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                        if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                            methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                        }
                    }
                 });
        }
    });
     ((CanCommitOffsets)  messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
    javaStreamContext.start();
    javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rishi for your response.In your code the offsetRange cannot access the variable initialized inside the block .And if I initialize outside the block with null, it says “local variable offsetRanges defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final”.But if I initialize as final with null outside the block and try to reassign it with actual value inside the block then it will not allow. Please advise

Comment: Let me know how to fix the issue with initializing offsetRanges, if i have to bring the commitAsync outside the block

Comment: @user1326784 i have written same program in scala and you definitely can bring out.

Comment: Can i use CommitSync in my case if i am using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream to read the messages

Answer (score 0):

The below code works.
But i am not sure if this commits the offset after processing into hive because the commitAsync block is before the hive store method call.

```
public void method1(SparkConf conf,String app) 
spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(conf.get("")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(context,
            new Duration(<spark duration>));
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(<topicnames>, <kafka Params>));
messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {
            OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
    }
});
            JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
                    return tuple2.value();
                }
            });

            records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                    if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                        methodToSaveDataInHive(rdd, <StructTypeSchema>,<OtherParams>);
                    }
                }
             });

javaStreamContext.start();
javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
```

}

To this code, if i add the below block(just after initializing the offsetRanges) to print the offset details, it doesnt work again, throws the same exception

```
messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {


                OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

               rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String,String>>>() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Iterator<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<String,String>> arg0) throws Exception {

                   OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];

                   System.out.println(o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());
                   }
            });

                ((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);

              }
              });
```

Please provide your comments